# Why does my function keep looping and how can i fix it?

Tags: python, function

```
import time 
import random
import sys
def code(): 
    user_num=()
    user_num=int(input("What number do you want from 0-30"))
    if user_num>30:
        print("number needs to be smaller")
        print("restart code and try again")
    else:
        pass
    if user_num<0:
        print("your number needs to be greater")
        print("restart code and try again")
    else:
        pass
    code()

code()
random_num=random.randint(0,1)
if random_num==user_num:
    print("your number is correct")
else:
    print("your number is incorrect")
    time.sleep(1)
    try_again=input("do you want to try again (yes/no")
    if try_again=="yes":
        code()
    else:
        print("ok. Bye")
```

i am very new to functions so sorry if this is a rookie mistake. Any help with functions will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: There is no condition in `code()` that prevents it from calling itself again at the end. That self-call to `code()` in the end is not conditional and there is nothing before that interrupting the function from reaching that point.

Comment: could you edit the code and fix that

Comment: Just use `return` where you find it appropriate. Also, if you intent to modify the global variable `user_num` you need to specify in `code()` that `user_num` is a global variable with `global user_num` at the beginning. As is, your code is not doing that, the value assigned to `user_num` will take no effect in the rest of the program.

Comment: Does my answer solved your problem :??

Answer (score 6):

At the very end of the "code" function you're calling it again

Comment: because if i don,t it wont be called.

Comment: Well then specify what exactly you wish that the program does :)

Comment: just doesn't keep looping the function and caries on with the code below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time 
import random
import sys
def code(): 
    user_num=()
    user_num=int(input("What number do you want from 0-30"))
    if user_num>30:
        print("number needs to be smaller")
        print("restart code and try again")
    else:
        pass
    if user_num<0:
        print("your number needs to be greater")
        print("restart code and try again")
    else:
        pass
    return user_num


random_num=random.randint(0,1)
user_num = code()
if random_num==user_num:
    print("your number is correct")
else:
    print("your number is incorrect")
    time.sleep(1)
    try_again=input("do you want to try again (yes/no")
    if try_again in "yes":
        user_num = code()
    else:
        print("ok. Bye")
```